# How to pass in JAVA string to Input ID

Tags: java, xpath

I have a sitring called "inputIDD", like : String InputIDD="input-2";
and want to pass this String to where : "input-2" is used like here:

```
String InputIDD = "input-2";
for (int a = 1; a <= 6; a++) 
{
  System.out.println("Value of a:" + a);
  System.out.println("Value of InputID:" + InputID);
  //   String y= Integer.toString(x);
  switch (a) {
    case 1:
      driver.findElementByXPath("(//input[@id='input-2'])[1]").sendKeys("0");
      break;
    case 2:
      driver.findElementByXPath("(//input[@id=InputIDD])[2]").sendKeys(ToAdd);
      break; // optional
```

etc,

`driver.findElementByXPath("(//input[@id='input-2'])[1]").sendKeys("0");` :   WORKS
`driver.findElementByXPath("(//input[@id=InputIDD])[1]").sendKeys("0");`:
Does not work

Why, any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

In case 2, you're passing the *string* InputIDD into the xpath expression, not the value of the variable InputIDD. You would need to do this instead:

```
 driver.findElementByXPath(String.format("(//input[@id=%s)[2]", InputIDD).sendKeys(ToAdd);
```

In the above statement the String.format method will swap in the value stored in InputIDD at the position denoted by the format string '%s'.

Comment: Hi Chris  I want to replace the 'input-2'  string by a STRING VARIABLE. :driver.findElementByXPath("(//input[@id='input-2'])[1]").sendKeys("0"); I tried: String InputIDD="input-2";  and used:

Comment: driver.findElementByXPath(String.format("(//input[@id='%s')[2]", InputIDD)).sendKeys(ToAdd);  to replace 'input-2'  by String Variable InputIDD, defined as  String InputIDD="input-2".if I do this then I get:  This code has no compiler errors but at runtime I get:  Exception iinvalid selector: Unable to locate an element with the xpath expression (//input[@id='input-2')[2] because of the following error:
SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'evaluate' on 'Document': The string '(//input[@id='input-2')[2]' is not a valid XPath expression.